# No recent apps screen after disabling the launcher

Tags: launcher, customization, bloatware, recents-screen

My phone came with a launcher I didn't really like very much. So I installed Nova Launcher and disabled the in-built launcher. Now the recent apps screen won't come up. I looked up and most of the suggestions were to install a custom rom, I can't install a custom rom because there is not custom recovery as well as custom rom for my phone. To get the recent apps screen should I enable the launcher or is there any other alternative?

Device model: Tecno Spark 7
Android Version: Android 11
In-built launcher: HiOS

Comment: I just remembered, I have another phone running custom rom(Havoc OS) and it came with two launchers - Pixel Launcher and Shady Launcher and on switching between the two, the recent apps screens changed. So, I'm guessing it probably is part of the launcher(maybe?).

Comment: You need to enable the stock launcher. There is no other way. I had read somewhere that since Android 9 recent view functionality was being provided by a launcher app. Nova launcher doesn't implement a recent view functionality and since you disabled stock launcher too you are left with none. Keep the stock launcher enabled but use Nova or whatever launcher you need as "default". This is what I had to do in my OnePlus 6 (Android 10).

Comment: I read [this](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-pie-recent-apps-customization/) and yes recent view functionality can be provided by a third-party launcher **but** it requires root.